# How to call a javascript function and on which text box event?

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I'm using Smarty and PHP for my website. For your reference I'm giving you the small code snippet of my code from smarty template.

```
{literal}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function get_tests_by_question_count() {
alert("Hi");}
</script>
{/literal}

<li style="margin-top:60px;">
              <label>Question Count</label>
              <div class="form-element">
                <select name="question_count" id="question_count">
                  <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
                  <option value=">" {if $duration == '>'} selected="selected" {/if}>More Than</option>
                  <option value="==" {if $duration == '=='} selected="selected" {/if}>Equal To</option>
                  <option value="<" {if $duration == '<'} selected="selected" {/if}>Less Than</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="question_count_no" id="question_count_no" style="width:30px;" value="{$question_count_no}" onChange="get_tests_by_question_count(); return false;"/>
              </div>
            </li>
```

Here I want to call the javascript function as soon as I finish with entering a value in a text field having ID **question_count_no**. The **onChange** is not working in my above code. Can you suggest me any trick to call the javascript function after I entered a value in a textbox. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: @Barmar:Now after typing in the value I have to press the enter key in order to call the function. But I want to call the function automatically after finishing entering the value into a textbox. Can you suggest me any trick for this?

Comment: How is it supposed to know when you're finished if you haven't pressed enter/tab or clicked on something else?

Comment: @Barmar:It will come to know after typing in number into a textbox. At that moment only I want to call the function. How could this be done?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the `keyup` event instead of `change`, so you can look for specific characters.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need to use the keyup event rather than onChange. On keyup event you can set a filter so that you code only works when some numeric value is entered.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/hQqSa/

```
<script>
    function get_tests_by_question_count(e) {
        if(/[0-9]/.test(e.value)) {
            alert(e.value);
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="question_count_no" id="question_count_no" style="width:30px;" onkeyup="get_tests_by_question_count(this); return false;"/>
```

Hope it helps you.